# Java Fork/Join computing sum of integers between 0 through Integer.MAX_VALUE leads to StackOverflow error

Tags: java, recursion, concurrency, fork-join

I am going to leverage multi-core CPU architecture using a sample which calculates the sum of all the integers 0 througn `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. My threshold is 5000000 integers. So I am spliting it recursively until the threshold it met. Then when it reaches the threshold I compute the sum. Finally all the sums are accumulated together to compute the final result. The problem is recursive in nature and fits in nicely with the Fork/join framework. But when I run it I am getting errors. Some times it is Stackoverflow error. Other time it is like this.

```
Exception in thread "ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-7" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$Node
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1198)
```

Here's my code:

```
public class ParallelSum extends RecursiveTask<Long> {
    private static final int THRESHOLD = 5000000;

    private final int start;
    private final int end;

    public ParallelSum(int start, int end) {
        super();
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
    }

    @Override
    protected Long compute() {
        // System.out.println("Start: " + start + " End: " + end);
        if (end - start > THRESHOLD) {
            return ForkJoinTask.invokeAll(createSubtasks()).stream().mapToLong(ForkJoinTask::join).sum();
        }
        return LongStream.rangeClosed(start, end).sum();
    }

    private Collection<RecursiveTask<Long>> createSubtasks() {
        final List<RecursiveTask<Long>> dividedTasks = new ArrayList<>();
        dividedTasks.add(new ParallelSum(start, end / 2));
        dividedTasks.add(new ParallelSum(end / 2 + 1, end));
        return dividedTasks;
    }
}
```

And the main method is like so,

```
public class ParallelSumTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final long sum = new ParallelSum(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE).compute();
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final long elapsedTime = endTime - startTime;
        System.out.println(sum + " was computed in " + elapsedTime + " milliseconds.");
    }
}
```

What is missing here? What I am doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception `NoClassDefFoundError` is most likely thrown because the JVM is running out of permanent generation space. Like the `StackOverflowException`, this is because the level of recursion generated by your algorithm is too deep.

There is a small error made when you create the tasks and split the work in two pieces. You should use the middle index as `(start + end) / 2` instead of `end / 2`:

```
dividedTasks.add(new ParallelSum(start, (start + end) / 2));
dividedTasks.add(new ParallelSum((start + end) / 2 + 1, end));
```

On my machine with the adjustment above I got the following output:

```
2738188572099084288 was computed in 1636 milliseconds.
```